How to Force TypeScript to Ignore react-native-moengage Errors
I'm working on a React Native project using the react-native-moengage module for analytics. Unfortunately, this library lacks proper TypeScript definitions, and I'm encountering TypeScript errors when running "npm run tsc."
Here's what I've tried so far on tsconfig.ts exclude and desc.d.ts:
tsconfig.ts exclude code
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules/react-native-moengage/*",
    "node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/react-native-moengage/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/react-native-moengage/src/**/*.ts",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
    "jest"
  ]

desc.d.ts
declare module 'react-native-moengage'

Despite these efforts, I'm still getting TypeScript errors from within the react-native-moengage module.
My environtment version:
react-native version: 0.72.13 
react-native-moengage: 10.2.0 
typescript-version: 4.8.4

How can I force TypeScript to completely ignore the react-native-moengage library and suppress the errors it's causing? Are there any other workarounds or configurations I should consider?
Screenshot tsc errors:
Typescript error screenshot

I'm unsure whether this would help, but have you tried to set skipLibCheck to true?

I tried this before, but still it doesn't solve typescript error

We have fixed the lint errors/warnings in the latest version of the react-native-moengage package (10.3.0).
Please update to the latest version. Find release notes

Thanks for fixing tsc issue in moengage module
